# how to find a basis for ker(T)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am struggling with an algebra problem here is what we got :

$$ T\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\ c&d \end{bmatrix}= a+d\;\; \; \; and \; \; \;\; L\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\ c&d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2a+d &a+b+d \\ a+c+d & -2a-d \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ T : Mat_{2\times 2}\rightarrow R \; \; and \; \; L : Mat_{2\times 2}\rightarrow Mat_{2\times 2}$$

I have to find a basis for ker(T) and the elements in the basis B1 , B2 , B3
and then show that ker(T) = im(L) ,

i'm stuck here if you could help me ,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$T\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=a+d=0\Leftrightarrow a=-d$$
So we quickly find that 
$$A_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\ A_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},A_{3}=\text{ and} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
are in the kernel of $T$. Note that they are linearly independent, $\ker(T)$ has at least dimension 3. Note that if $\ker(T)$ has dimension 4, then $T=0$ which is a contradiction, so $\{A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\}$ is a basis for the kernel of $T$.

Also note that $LA_{1}=A_{1},\ LA_{2}=A_{2}$ and $LA_{3}=A_{3}$ and
$$L\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
So $\text{im}(L)$ has dimension 3 and $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\in\text{im}(L)$. It follows that  $\{A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\}$ is a basis for the image of $L$. So $\ker(T)=\text{im}(L)$.

Comment: Hey floris , thanks for your answer , much appreciated

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with writing the matrix $L$. If you mean how to write $L$ with respect to basis $\{A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},A_{4}\}$, then I'd say it should be fairly obvious that $L_{1,1}=L_{2,2}=L_{3,3}=1$ with the rest of $L$ zeroes.

Comment: Sorry yes it is what i meant with $A_{4}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 \\ 1& -2 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: and sorry to ask again and bother you , but could we prove that ker(T) = im(L) using 
 double inclusion and calculating L(M) − M for M belonging to ker(T)

Comment: In general calculating $L(M)-M$ for $M$ belonging to $\ker(T)$ will not be helpful. What you could is note that $$TL\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=2a+d-2a-d=0$$, so $\text{im}(L)\subset \ker(T)$, and from my answer above we already know that $\ker(T)\subset\text{im}(L)$ as the basis of $\ker(T)$ is contained in the image of $L$.